# remove delimiter in the middle of a string

Tags: php

I have a string: `item1|item2|item 3|yyyy-mm-dd`.

`|` is the delimiter for the items. the date is appended to `item1 | item2 | item3 |` and you can add more items after item3 so there can be a indefinite number of items. i want to be able to remove the last delimiter. is there a way to do this? I know i could trim the end with `rtrim()` but I'm not sure how to go about this when it's indefinite and not at the end of the string. this is what i used for the string with the delimiter at the end:

```
$exp = explode("|", $row['item'],-1);
$li = rtrim($row['item'], '|');
if(is_null($exp[1])) {
    echo $li;
} 
else {
    echo str_replace("|", ", ", $li);
}
```

What I did here was I checked if there were more than one input for `item`. If there's only one, it would simply just remove the last delimiter. Otherwise, it'd remove the last delimiter but also replace the pipeline `|` with a comma `,`. I want the output to look like this:

```
item1, item2, item3 yyyy-mm-dd
```

Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: So the aim is to turn `item1|item2|item 3|yyyy-mm-dd` into `item1, item2, item3 yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes that's the output needed

Comment: Please offer more than one sample input, so that we can understand how the data can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the array by `|` pop off the end item using [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and then [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back together with `,`, then finally append the last item (return value of array_pop) at the end.

```
<?php
$str = 'item1|item2|item 3|yyyy-mm-dd';

$array = explode('|', $str);

$last = array_pop($array);

echo implode (', ', $array).' '.$last;
```

https://3v4l.org/ShFJX

**Result:**

`item1, item2, item 3 yyyy-mm-dd`

---

If you have a string like: `item1|item2|item 3||item 4|||yyyy-mm-dd`, you could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
<?php
$str = 'item1|item2|item 3||item 4|||yyyy-mm-dd';

$array = explode('|', $str);

$array = array_filter($array);

$last = array_pop($array);

echo implode (', ', $array).' '.$last;
```

https://3v4l.org/W0kPn

**Result:**

```
item1, item2, item 3, item 4 yyyy-mm-dd
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:-

1. Use `explode()` the string on the character, `|`,
2. Popout the date using a `array_pop()`
3. Concatenate the items in the array to a string using `implode()`
4. Concat the string with the date

> ```
> $str = "item1|item2|item 3|yyyy-mm-dd";
>
> $strArray = explode("|", $str);
>
> $date = array_pop($strArray);
>
> echo $newStr = implode($strArray, ", ") . " " . $date;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace("/\|([^|]+)$/", " $1", "item1|item2|item 3|yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Result:
item1|item2|item 3 yyyy-mm-dd

This regular expression replacement operation will remove last pipe (|) from your string. I have added a space here (before $1 in second argument above) to separate the last token for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single `preg_replace()` call with two patttern -- effectively avoiding the conversion of the data to an array then back to a string again.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WAESg))

```
$row['item']='item1|item2|item 3||item 4|||yyyy-mm-dd';

$row['item']=preg_replace(['~\|+(?=[^|]+$)~','~\|+~'],[' ',', '],$row['item']);

echo $row['item'];
```

Output:

```
item1, item2, item 3, item 4 yyyy-mm-dd
```

Breakdown:

The first pattern uses a positive lookahead to target the pipe(s) before the final value in the input -- that pipe(s) is replaced with a space.

The second pattern targets all remaining pipes (matching multiple consecutive pipes where possible) and replaces them with comma-space.